# Postgres materialized view: no performance gain

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, materialized-view

I've created a materialized view to cache results of joining about 15 tables.

Unfortunately, `select * from mv_cache` takes the same amount of time as the original joins. Am I doing anything wrong? Where is the promised performance gain?

Edited:

Version: PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424) 10.3.1 20210424, 64-bit

Exec. plan link: https://explain.depesz.com/s/ydKZ#html

Comment: Obviously the performance problem is the amount of data you are retrieving, not the actual JOINs. The first step in analyzing any performance problem is to run `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` then post the execution plan as formatted text (no screen shots please). For more information on how to ask performance question, please see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: The docs just say it is "often" faster.  If someone made you a promise, figure out who it was, and ask *them* to defend it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! If such a `"performance gain"` were indeed `"promised"`, then the feature in question would be the default and there would be no other option - there would be no point in having any other option. There are no `go-faster` sections in the `postgresql.conf` file - there are options for **a reason**. In certain circumstances, performing operations using one option or another can be faster or slower depending on many factors (be it using postgresql.conf entries and/or rewriting your query and/or using materialised views.... list is endless).

Comment: These options can in turn depend on CPU, RAM, HDD configuration, Network, phases of the moon, the azimuth of Venus at full-tide, your first-born's birth-sign &c... - again, the list is endless.  (that's why us DBAs get paid the big bucks! :-) )

Comment: Two of the most promising features of MV are the ability to add indexes that can't exist on the original, because the index would cross original table boundaries, or it indexes aggregation results.

Comment: Astrology aside, the MV *should* certainly be faster than joining 15 tables. How much (and why not?) depends on missing details. Disclose information [as instructed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) to clear this up.

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing exec plan right away...just fixed that. Any other information you need, just give me to know.

Comment: The query runs in 10 **milli**seconds - how fast do you need that to be?

Comment: DBeaver executes the query in about 5 seconds...starting to think that this is our network who introduces delays...

Comment: Well, the query returns roughly 10MB of data. Of course this is going to take some time. Displaying that many rows also incurs an overhead

Comment: So execution time was confused with data transfer / display. I think we can close this question?

Comment: Yes, this can be closed. Thank you guys for paying your time